# Access log for git

Tags: git

How can I find out who has cloned / pulled a project in git? I'm finding all great tools for tracking the files, but is there a way to see who has had accessed them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming people are accessing the repository via ssh, you could use `sshd`'s access log to get a general sense.

Beyond that, however, there aren't any "access logs" built into Git itself. If you use something like `gitolite` to serve repositories, it has its own logging functionality I believe.

Comment: Gitolite has fairly detailed logging, and you'll get what you want as long as you forego public access (via http or the git protocol) and force everyone to use ssh authentication.

Answer (score 3):

git uses `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` for communicating with other machines. You can try wrapping those and logging access.